# Dynamic Div changes width on mouseover

Tags: css, html

in my project i have a few dynamically generated Divs.
The code, that defines these Divs looks like this:
`"<div class=\"DivStyle\"  runat=\"server\" \">";`
The `DivStyle` class looks like this:

```
.DivStyle:hover  
{  
    display: inline-block;  
    border: 3px solid rgb(242, 209, 153);  
    border-style: dashed  
}
```

My problem is: when i put my mouse over these Divs they shrink in their width.
Now follows an example for **one** of these Divs.
Normally it looks like this:
[image: Normal look and feel]
That is what is supposed to look like *always*...
But when my mouse hovers over it, it changes to this:
[image: Wrong look and feel]
Why does that happen?
And what can i do to prevent it?

Comment: The `:hover` style is for the little dashed line around the Pictures and Text. but it is not supposed to shrink like that.

Comment: Could you post you .DivStyle css class without the hover selector?

Comment: Show your code - or an example [CssDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs).Else, its tuff to figure out where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Search all your css for :hover, see if there's another entry that is causing this. It could be a parent element.

Comment: No, i checked the generated HTML and the div has no parent element with any style whatsoever.